# Problem using Retroguard to obfuscate swt application

Tags: swt, obfuscation

I was trying to obfuscate SWT code using Retroguard, but after obfuscation, I can't start the jar it has created. Please advise. Thanks.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\zzz\My Documents>java -jar retroguard.jar swt-orig.j
ar

C:\Documents and Settings\zzz\My Documents>java -jar out.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.eclipse.swt.inter
nal.win32.OS.GetVersionExW(Lorg/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/ar;)Z
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.GetVersionExW(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at i.z.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the DLL containing SWT native methods. Was it packed into **swt-orig.jar**? Perhaps Retroguard removed or altered it?

You may also wish to read about the limitations of obfuscation and about alternative ways to protect your code in my article **[Protect Your Java Code - Through Obfuscators And Beyond](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)**.

Comment: I think the SWT dll was packed into jar file, because I was able to run it by using
java -jar swt-orig.jar

Comment: Okay, can you check that to make sure and if yes, find out whether is it still present in out.jar?